# AWS CodeDeploy does not have the permissions required to assume the role

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up CI/CD with AWS + EC2 and am stuck when creating Deployment Group. The role of CodeDeploy has policies AWSCodeDeployRole and AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS but it throws an error. I tried giving it Admin rights but it is still not enough. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you doing infrastructure as code or are you doing this in AWS console ?

Comment: Hey I am using AWS console and thanks, first post :)

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to ECS ?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly this: https://blog.devgenius.io/deploy-a-reactjs-application-to-aws-ec2-instance-using-aws-codepipeline-3df5e4157028

Comment: so when you try to add the service URL, it doesn't let you create a deployment group ? I think I know whats happening, but do you get any error ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have a role that has the permissions required for the codedeploy to perform the deployment. What you are missing here is, You should have a trust policy defined in the role that allows codedeploy to assume the role.

1. Goto IAM console and select the role from the roles section
2. Click Trust relationships
3. Click Edit trust Relationships
4. Add the following trust policy to allow code deploy service to assume this role.

   ```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [
              "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
   ```

Reference: [Create a service role for CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html)

Comment: That has solved it, thank you! The error message was exactly as the title, I would have never known how to solve this as a newbie!

Comment: Glad to help. Stackoverflow is a great community :)